# Html.ActionLink does not pass my id

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-5, actionlink

In my view I have a ActionLink that passes an Id to another View. I used this multiple times but for some reason it does not work on this ActionLink. I even tried with a AJAX POST call in javascript but with no success either. Am I doing something wrong? If so, I am not seeing what.

**Controller:**

The parameter Id in this function is 0 and should be filled.

```
public ActionResult NieuwPriveBericht(int Id)
    {
        TblPER_Personeelslid Sender = BCL.GetEmployeeByLoginName(Session["LoginName"].ToString());
        TblPER_Personeelslid Receiver = BCL.GetEmployeeById(Id);

        var Model = new TblALG_PrvBericht();
        Model.Datum = DateTime.Now.Date;
        Model.Zender = Sender.IDPersoneelslid;
        Model.Ontvanger = Receiver.IDPersoneelslid;

        ViewBag.ReceiverName = Receiver.Voornaam + " " + Receiver.Naam;

        return View(Model);
    }

 public ActionResult PriveBerichten()
    {
        ViewBag.SelectedEmployee = "";

        var Model = new PriveBerichten();
        return View(Model);
    }
```

**View:**

If I debug my view I clearly see @Model.SelectedOption filled.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("PriveBerichten", "Home", @Model, FormMethod.Post))
{

@Html.ActionLink("Nieuw bericht maken", "NieuwPriveBericht", new { Id = @Model.SelectedOption }, new { @class = "button-add" })
}
```

**AJAX CALL**

```
$("#DdlEmployees").change(function () {
    var SelectedEmployee = $('#DdlEmployees option:selected').val();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'PriveBerichten?SelectedEmployee=' + SelectedEmployee, // this works
        dataType: "json",
        data: $('form').serialize(),
        success: function () {
            alert("test"); // does not show
        },
        error: function () {
        }
    });
})
```

Comment: This is not original question anymore, you should post different questions separately.

Answer (score 1):

If you didn't set up the id of route is "Id", you need to use "id". Also delete "@Model" in the BeginForm.

**Action**

```
public ActionResult NieuwPriveBericht(int id)
    {
//
    }
```

**View:**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("PriveBerichten", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{

 @Html.ActionLink("Nieuw bericht maken", "NieuwPriveBericht", 
               new { id = @Model.SelectedOption }, new{ @class = "button-add" })
}
```

Comment: In my route it is declared as id but I use Id in other views and it works aswell. Doesn't make any difference. And why should I remove @Model ? Any reasoning?

Comment: The third parameter should be object routeValues field, I don't know why you're passing the Model value to this field.

Comment: True. I used it from another project someone else made. Never really paid notice to it.

Comment: This is not the solution :( I removed @Model from BeginForm and it didn't change anything really. I have no clue whats wrong... I have another ActionLink on the same view redirecting me to another view with a parameter and that works perfectly.

Comment: If it's still not working, I think the value of "Model.SelectedOption" is wrong. You should check the value of "Model.SelectedOption", maybe the type of it  is not an integer

Comment: @NanouPonette, "int Id = 8", that's mean the default parameter Id value will be "8". It's nothing to do with the Id value from ActionLink. That's why you still get "0".

Comment: @NanouPonette, For test, you can try to pass an integer value to Id in the ActionLink. like below:  new { Id = 8 }

Comment: I know that but If I used Id in my function it it still 0 while it has a default value of 8. U understand?

Comment: hi @NanouPonette, I just want you to solve the problem. I don't care if I can get the points or not. I know the purpose why you try to set up the default value. but, think about this. The NieuwPriveBericht action method will never be called, unless the user click something using the ActionLink, then the ActionLinke will pass Id value to your Action method. That's why even you set the default parameter value, it'll still wait the value from ActionLink, that means equal to you don't set it up. I hope you can find the solution.

Comment: I'm very grateful you trying to help me @@Lin. I did what you told me to do and If i put in my action link Id = 8 it does get passed to the function. I don't get it why @Model.SelectedOption does not work when its an int in my model and its being filled.

Comment: @NanouPonette, If you post the function that you set the SelectedOption value to, I can take a look. Usually dropdown list has Value and Text, I think you may passed the text value to SelectedOption, and it's not integer type.

Comment: @NanouPonette What is the generated link you see in the browser's source? (Just to be sure: `@Model.SelectedOption` does not change when you change a select element on the same webpage since the view is already rendered)

Comment: @Marthijn I know Model.SelectedOption does not change thats why I fill this in my Controller. I have this localhost/Home/NieuwPriveBericht/8 link when I used new { Id = 8 } instead of new { Id = Model.SelectedOption }

Comment: @Marthijn Even when I tried with a ViewBag instead of my model property it does not work.

Comment: @NanouPonette I think there is something wrong in the action creating the viewmodel. Just use breakpoints to see which values are passed to the view.

Comment: @Marthijn I already did that multiple times. Everything is passed correctly :(

Comment: @NanouPonette well there is one thing that might be an issue. Once I noticed some strange behaviour with strongly typed views and `Id` properties in anoymous objects. Try rename `Id` to for example `myId` (`new { myId = ... }`) and see if the value is correct.

Comment: @Marthijn Thx for helping me btw! I tried this but with no success again. I even have this ActionLink above it in my for and here it does get passed correctly:     Html.ActionLink("Verwijder", "VerwijderPriveBericht", "Home", new { Id = @Model.LstPrvBericht[i].IdPrvBericht }, new { class = "button-remove"})

Comment: @NanouPonette Well I'm out of options then, maybe when you post the code of the `ActionResult` that generates the view (that contains the faulty `ActionLink`) we can find the problem.

Comment: @Marthijn I added the ActionResult that generates the view but theres nothing special in it.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for showing the ActionResult that generates the view. I think this is your problem:

```
var Model = new PriveBerichten();
return View(Model);
```

I assume your class `PriveBerichten` contains the `SelectedOption` property? If you do not change/initialize this property value in the constructor of `PriveBerichten` it is 0 by default, and so it will be 0 in your actionlink.

Comment: But I have a AJAX method which gets triggered by selecting something in the dropdown list which then triggers a ActionResult where I return a model with SelectedOption filled. You understand what I mean ? So yes the first the view starts its 0 but thats okay. I only need it to be filled in the post. You have to select a user first then press on a button and on this button the value needs to get passed.

Comment: Well, there is nothing wrong with your ActionLink, and if that ActionResult returns a model with the right values and right PartialView the only thing left is that you AJAX method is not updating the DOM with the new view (which contains the correct actionlink). You can use something like FireBug to verify if the server is sending the right data.

Comment: What I noticed is the POST is send which I can see in FireBug but the page does not refresh. Could this be the problem?

Comment: The flow is as follows: 1: select an option in the select. 2: an AJAX call is made to the server. 3: the server returns a partial view (with the correct actionlink). 4: the onSuccess callback of your AJAX call needs to replace the old html with the new html.

Comment: I added my javascript in the question. I think the problem is there. The success function doesn't get triggered it seems.

Comment: The `success()` callback is deprecated, try `done()` in this way: `$.ajax({..}).done(function() {alert('done!');});` , see http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/